# Excel determine previous Month and Year from an existing date

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a date field `7/12/2016` and I need to extract the previous Month Year from this date.  What is the best formula?

Needed format of final data `Jun-2016`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to return it as date, use `DATE`, `YEAR` and `MONTH` function combination.

```
=DATE(YEAR(DateField), MONTH(DateField)-1, 1)
```

Then use *Custom Number Format*: `mmm-yyyy`
<sup>Note: **DateField** should be the cell reference containing your actual date.</sup>

Comment: your sample still returns current field value of 7/1/2016 , it need it to be Jun 2016 (the previous months value)

Comment: @KarenSchaefer opps, sorry. Forgot to less month by 1. It should be ok now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Previous Month name using sharepoint calculated column as follows

```
=TEXT(DATE(YEAR([Due Date]),MONTH([Due Date])-1,"1"),"MMMM")
```